# How to get reCaptcha HTML content from cross domain Iframe?

Tags: javascript, c#

Im trying to get reCaptcha HTML content which is inside an iframe of my website, using c#. The problem is that it is cross domain and can't reach the content. For example, I want to get the URL of the Download URL Audio Challenge.

**What I have tried?**

Option 1:
- In a Windows Form application, I created a WebBrowser.

- Navigate my site.
- Do an HTTP GET request
- On DocumentCompleted event, read the HTML.

Option 2:

- In a Windows Form Application, I have added Awesomium dll.
- I have created a WebControl
- Assigned a WebSession to the WebControl using WebSecurity as false.
- Navigate my site
- On LoadingFrameComplete get the HTML.

**What I Get?**

The content of my website and the tag of the reCaptcha iframe, but not its content with the image to solve, or the link to get the audio challenge.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is against the principle reCaptcha is used